# how to fix .count to work for all inputs?

Tags: python

I'm working on zybook labs here is question:

Write a program whose input is a string which contains a character and a phrase, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the phrase.

Ex: If the input is:

n Monday
the output is: 1

Ex: If the input is:
z Today is Monday

the output is: 0

Ex: If the input is:
n It's a sunny day

the output is: 2

Case matters.

Ex: If the input is:
n Nobody

the output is: 0

n is different than N.

My codes works only in half way here is code:

```
user_input = input() 
words_list = user_input.split() # to put user input into list

word = words_list[0] # to take character for counting 
new_list = words_list.pop(1) # to make new list without character for count

count = new_list.count(word) # count character in new_list

print(count)
```

my code works for inputs: n Monday, z Today is Monday.
It doesn't work for inputs: n It's a sunny day, t this is a sentence with many t's

I have no idea why it doesn't work for other inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
new_list = words_list.pop(1)
```

That takes the second word in the list and stores it into `new_list`.  The rest of the words are still in `words_list`, but you don't check them.

And actually, you don't need to split this at all.

```
user_input = input()
target = user_input[0]
count = user_input[2:].count(target)
```

Comment: Right.  I debated that when I posted it.  I suspect it won't be an issue, but you're right that it's a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input() 
words_list = user_input.split(" ", 1) # to put user input into list

word = words_list[0] # to take character for counting 
new_list = words_list.pop(1) # to make new list without character for count

count = new_list.count(word) # count character in new_list

print(count)
```

See if it solves the problem

Comment: This is a little confusing: `# to make new list without character for count`. `new_list` here is a string, not a list. It's also not really necessary to split the string.

Comment: This answer combines some good stuff (passing a second argument to `split` to tell it to only split once) with some really confusing and bad stuff later (strings in variables with `list` in their name, etc.).